# Storybook with craco - call a different verson of react-scripts

Tags: create-react-app, storybook, craco

Storybook currently calls `react-scripts`. However, I've got some parts of the CRA config overriden with `craco`. It means my application is invoked with `craco ...`, rather than `react-scripts ...`.

Is there a clean solution to have Storybook call `craco` instead?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I came up with is this :

.storybook/main.js :

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.js'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/preset-create-react-app',
    '@storybook/addon-actions',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-viewport/register',
    '@storybook/addon-knobs/register',
  ],
  webpackFinal(config, { configType }) {
    return {
      ...config,
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          ...config.resolve.alias,
          '~': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/'),
        },
      },
    };
  },
};
```

I was only using the alias feature in my craco file, so here I override webpack config from storybook and only add the alias parameter. For your case, you'll need to add your own config.

Answer (score 1):

The @FR073N solution is good, but since the lasts versions, this throw an error.

One line was missing to fully override correctly the webpack config.

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.js'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/preset-create-react-app',
    '@storybook/addon-actions',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-viewport/register',
    '@storybook/addon-knobs/register',
  ],
  webpackFinal(config, { configType }) {
    return {
      ...config,
      resolve: {
        ...config.resolve, // <= HERE
        alias: {
          ...config.resolve.alias,
          '~': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/'),
        },
      },
    };
  },
};
```

Answer (score -2):

I've successfully used [storybook-preset-craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/storybook-preset-craco) with `@storybook@6.3.5` and `react-scripts@4.0.3` and `@craco/craco@6.2.0` in a new CRA TypeScript project.

Comment: This library is completely broken, it doesn't work. It can only work when `.storybook` is inside `/src`, but storybook only works when `.storybook` is in the root directory.